# Group/Summarize each row with removal row if total quantity is 0

Tags: sql, sql-server

How to group/summarize as example image below.
The same data will be grouped based on Date and Item columns.
The quantity will be sum.

**If the negative quantity is more than total quantity of the min date (total qty = 0), that row will be removed.**

This condition will continue for the next min date as well.

In this case 1-Jan-2020 and 2-Jan-2020 will be removed because it negative quantity is more than total of those 2 days.

In case you want sample table, please use script below.

```
CREATE TABLE #temp_table(
[id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[trans_date] [date] NOT NULL,
[item] [nvarchar](40) NOT NULL,
[qty] [int] NOT NULL,
)
INSERT INTO #temp_table (     trans_date,     item,     qty )
VALUES
(     '1-Jan-2020',      'Item A',     2  )
INSERT INTO #temp_table (     trans_date,     item,     qty )
VALUES
(     '2-Jan-2020',      'Item A',     4  )
INSERT INTO #temp_table (     trans_date,     item,     qty )
VALUES
(     '3-Jan-2020',      'Item B',     1  )
INSERT INTO #temp_table (     trans_date,     item,     qty )
VALUES
(     '3-Jan-2020',      'Item A',     3  )
INSERT INTO #temp_table (     trans_date,     item,     qty )
VALUES
(     '4-Jan-2020',      'Item A',     -1  )
INSERT INTO #temp_table (     trans_date,     item,     qty )
VALUES
(     '5-Jan-2020',      'Item A',     -6  )
INSERT INTO #temp_table (     trans_date,     item,     qty )
VALUES
(     '6-Jan-2020',      'Item A',     4  )


SELECT * FROM #temp_table 


DROP TABLE #temp_table
```

[image: Example Image]

My 1st attempt was

```
select 
trans_date
, item
, SUM(qty)
from temp_table 
group BY 
trans_date
, item
```

My 2nd attempt, this attempt is feel like I'm lacking of some condition to reduce the next row when I first row is 0.

```
select 
temp_table.trans_date
, temp_table.item
, SUM(temp_table.qty) + SUM(neg_table.neg_qty)
from  temp_table
OUTER APPLY (
SELECT ISNULL( SUM(neg.qty), 0) AS neg_qty FROM pca_temp_table neg
WHERE 1=1
and temp_table.item = neg.item
and neg.qty < 0
)  as neg_table
WHERE qty > 0
group BY 
trans_date
, item
```

Comment: I can't make sense of your negative/positive condition - I recommend showing your working in detail.

Comment: Just edited my attempt.
It's simple and yet I'm running out of idea.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this query works fine for you:

```
select MAX(CASE WHEN Quantity>0 THEN DATE ELSE NULL END), ITEM, SUM(Quantity)
from @T 
group BY ITEM
```

Comment: This is not working if there is more + qty.
Let's say we have another row 06-Jan-2020 with + 4 qty
I want the final result for item A to contain both 03-Jan-2020 = 2 and 06-Jan-2020 = 4

Comment: i think 'Cursor' can be a better option for this @Krsnik195 to avoid future bugs related to this.

Comment: I try to avoid using Cursor because I'm afraid it will be too slow but it look like I don't have a choice.